# Problem calling method with generic parameter by reflection

Tags: c#, generics

So here are the simplified class :

```
// base class for all object
public class TrainingClass
{
    public double NetSurface { get; set; } = 0;
}

// one sample object
public class Blank : TrainingClass
{
    public double Height { get; set; } = 0;
    public double Width { get; set; } = 0;     
}

// the handling class
public class RegModel<T> where T : TrainingClass
{
    // empty constructor
    public RegModel() { }

    // 2 methods that use data of type T
    public void Train(List<T> datas) {}
    public void Solve(T data) {}        
}
```

Typically i can easily call them one by one but since the amount of class will go in excess of 3,000 i wanted t make the call generic. What i have achieved is the following :

```
// create the data type the generic need to be of
//(this is parameter in the real code)
Type dataType = typeof(Blank);

// create a dummy list of data (this is actually a property in the 
// class in the real code it's of TrainingClass type to allow for generic)
var datas = new List<TrainingClass>();

// create the generic base type
Type genericClass = typeof(RegModel<>);

// create the generic type
Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(dataType);

// create the class
var rm = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);

// get the train method
var trainMethod = constructedClass.GetMethod("Train");

// invoke the train method passing the List<TrainingData>
trainMethod.Invoke(rm, new[] { datas });
```

the train method throw me a type exception

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ConsoleApp2334.TrainingClass]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

I also tried making a generic call for the `Train` method like so and get an error saying it's not generic

```
var trainMethodGeneric = trainMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Blank));
```

and the error is

> Train(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp2334.Blank]) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

So in the first ace it whine about wrong generic parameters and on the second one it whine about not being generic or not "define" as one. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Right, `Train(List<T> x)` is not a generic method. It's a member of a generic type (whence the type parameter for that List), but it doesn't have its *own* type parameter. You need to provide a type parameter for the *type*.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks, that clear off my confusion on the error messages themselves. That make sense.

Comment: It'd definitely throw an exception; how do you expect to pass an object of type `List<TrainingClass>` as a parameter of type `List<Blank>`! `List<Blank>` is the type of your parameter given your constructed type if you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a `RegModel<Blank>`, and attempted to call `Train` with a `List<TrainingClass>`. This will not work because `Train` called on a `RegModel<Blank>` will only accept `List<Blank>`.

You need to have a way to convert a `List<TrainingClass>` to a `List<Blank>`. Or more generally, given a `Type` and a `List<TrainingClass>` convert the list to a list of that `Type`. One such way to do this is using this method:

```
// Note that although it says IList here, this method actually returns a List<T> at runtime
// We don't know the actual type of the list at compile time. The best we know
// is that it is some kind of a list.
static System.Collections.IList ConvertListToType<T>(Type type, List<T> list) {
    Type constructedListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var newList = (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
    list.ForEach(x => newList.Add(x));
    return newList;
}
```

You can call this method to convert `datas` to the required type before you pass it to `Train`.

Comment: I can't instantiate the class as `TrainingClass` The reason is that the library that uses that only read the properties of the `TrainingClass` class and not `Blank` class if we do that. But if i pass an object of type `Blank` it does see all the properties.

Comment: What is this library that you are using? How are you using it? What does it do? How are `Blank` and `TrainingClass` related? @Franck

Comment: `Blank` is one of the couple thousands of class i have. `TrainingClass` is the main class that contain the common property. The Library is ML.NET, microsoft machine learning. They have a method where you pass an object with properties to train the model. It only read the property of the type of object you pass. If you create the `Blank` object it only see the property `height` and `width`. if you pass a `new Blank() as TrainingClass` it only see `NetSurface`

Comment: @Franck Then `datas` has to be of `List<Blank>` as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes certainly. But i won't copy paste 3000 times this code for every class i need. If you know how to convert a collection to another type without the actual class as written that would be perfect. aka i can't do `var newList = Data.Cast<Blank>()`. That would mean i need to copy paste the code for every combinaison of classes.

Comment: @Franck Converting `List<TrainingClass>` to `List<SomethingElse>` is a thing that we can do. The more important question is whether the list actually contains `SomethingElse`. Is every element in the `List` a `SomethingElse`?

Comment: That's it. completely forgot `List` was a class an i could call a make generic on it. It works wonderfully. And yes the list will contain derived type of `TrainingClass` filled through reflection with an `Activator.CreateInstance`